# Memory leak problems on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks, handler

I have recently discovered that one of my apps has a major memory leak but cant seem to find the cause of this, I have tried inspecting the java heap dump on android studio but cant and don't know exactly how to find what is causing the leak in the specific activity (So any tips on that would also be nice), and I the converted .hprof file is not compatible on MAT for some reason.. So I was searching my code and came across a small piece that I probably didn't think over twice and wanted to know if this might cause a memory leak :

```
public void initializeProgressUpdate(){
if (shouldContinue){
    postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Do some stuff
            initializeProgressUpdate();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

}
```

or something like this :

```
private static class SetItems extends Handler implements Runnable{

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ListAdapter adapter;
String link;

public SetRelatedVideos(RecyclerView recyclerView, ListAdapter adapter, String link){
    this.recyclerView= recyclerView;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    try {
        ArrayList<item> items = (ArrayList) msg.obj;

        adapter.itemsArrayList = items;
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ArrayList<item> items = getItems();
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.obj = items;
        sendMessage(msg);


    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I always knew that handlers should be static on android to avoid memory leaks in case of a delayed message but is the "main" handler in this case static ? And could this be the cause of a memory leak? 
Excuse my English if the question is not very clear.

Comment: This is not real code.  The statement `adapter.itemsArrayList = items;` is not compileable.  Also, you appear to have the wrong name for your constructor.  Please provide a MCVE; i.e. a minimal, complete, compileable example that actually exhibits the memory leak.  Unless you show us real code, it is not possible to say whether the code actually leaks memory.

Comment: @StephenC `ListAdapter` is a custom implemented `RecyclerView.Adapter` with an attribute `ArrayList` called `itemsArrayList` so `adapter.itemsArrayList = items` changes the value of itemsArrayList in the ListAdapter object called adapter. I cannot put the whole code since it would be quite long so I tried to put the necessary, sorry if it wasnt clear :/

Comment: @StephenC what I wanted to know in this case was would passing the RecyclerView or a reference to the current Activity for example as an argument to a runnable that would be used as a thread cause a memory leak?

Comment: I can't see where you are doing that.  Re the MCVE ... I'm not asking you to post all of your code.  I'm asking you to write a stripped-down version that 1) compiles, 2) exhibits the problem when you run it, and 3) is small enough for you to post and us to read.